# return several parameter from lua C function

Tags: c, lua

I want to get several parameters in Lua from a C function. 
I tried to push several arguments on the lua stack:

```
static int myFunc(lua_State *state)
{
    lua_pushnumber(state, 1);
    lua_pushnumber(state, 2);
    lua_pushnumber(state, 3);

    return 1;
}
```

and call it in Lua like this:

```
local a,b,c = myFunc()
```

Unfortunately b and c values are nil. I dont want to write a function for every value I need but to take advantage of Luas capabilities to retrieve several arguments from a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value of the C function is the number of values returned.

Change it to `return 3;` and you're good to go.

Here, have a reference from *Programming in Lua*:

```
static int l_sin (lua_State *L) {
  double d = lua_tonumber(L, 1);  /* get argument */
  lua_pushnumber(L, sin(d));  /* push result */
  return 1;  /* number of results */
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you. I thought this is just a status if the function call was alright.

Comment: @Objective My humble suggestion would be to start checking in references instead of guessworking next time :).